# radio button in gridview template field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a exam web application in ASP.NET. I am using grid-view for showing question and the possible answers. I set size of grid view is 1 so it display only one question on a page-index. I am using radio button for multiple choice option.

When I select a radio button and going to next question or next page index of grid-view and come again previous question then I see that the radio button which I selected previously is not selected. What should I do for this?

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        GridLines="None" Height="380px" 
                        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
                        onprerender="GridView1_PreRender" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" PageSize="1" 
                        ShowHeader="False" style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" 
                        Width="100%">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table style=" width:100%; height: 550px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style6" colspan="2" colspan="3" 
                                                
                                                style="border-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: inset;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" Text="Question No :-"></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" 
                                                    Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style4" colspan="2" colspan="2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Question:-" 
                                                    Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
                                                &nbsp;<br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" 
                                                    Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style9" style=" padding-top:10px">
                                                A:-<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                    Font-Bold="False" 
                                                    oncheckedchanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>' />
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style1" rowspan="4" style=" padding-top:10px">
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Height="149px" 
                                                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' Width="449px" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style9">
                                                B:-<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                    Font-Bold="False" 
                                                    oncheckedchanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged" Text='<%# Eval("B") %>' />
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style9">
                                                C:-<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                    Font-Bold="False" 
                                                    oncheckedchanged="RadioButton3_CheckedChanged" Text='<%# Eval("C") %>' />
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style9">
                                                D:-<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                    Font-Bold="False" 
                                                    oncheckedchanged="RadioButton4_CheckedChanged" Text='<%# Eval("D") %>' />
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" BackColor="#006699" BorderStyle="None" 
                                                    Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White" Height="34px" 
                                                    Text="Next&gt;&gt;&gt;" Width="230px" />
                                                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" BackColor="#006699" BorderStyle="None" 
                                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CommandName="Next" Font-Bold="True" 
                                                    Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White" Height="34px" Text="Mark for Review &amp; Next" 
                                                    Width="229px" />
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#006699" BorderStyle="None" 
                                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CommandName="Save" Font-Bold="True" 
                                                    Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White" Height="34px" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
                                                    Text="Save and Next" Width="230px" />
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                                    <table style=" width:100%; height: 550px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style9" colspan="2">
                                                Q<span ID="GridView1_ctl02_Label14" style="font-size:Large;">0</span> .
                                                <span ID="GridView1_ctl02_Label6" style="font-size:Large;font-weight:bold;">abc</span> 
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style9">
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp; C:-<span style="font-size:Large;font-weight:normal;"><input 
                                                    ID="GridView1_ctl02_RadioButton3" name="GridView1$ctl02$RadioButton3" 
                                                    onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'GridView1$ctl02$RadioButton3\',\'\')', 0)" 
                                                    type="radio" value="RadioButton3" /><label 
                                                    for="GridView1_ctl02_RadioButton3">abc</label></span>
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style6" colspan="2" 
                                                style=" border-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: inset;">
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp; A:-<span style="font-size:Large;font-weight:bold;" 
                                                    ID="GridView1_ctl02_Label4"><input 
                                                    ID="GridView1_ctl02_RadioButton1" name="GridView1$ctl02$RadioButton1" 
                                                    onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'GridView1$ctl02$RadioButton1\',\'\')', 0)" 
                                                    type="radio" value="RadioButton1" /><label 
                                                    for="GridView1_ctl02_RadioButton1">abc</label></span>
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style1" rowspan="4" style=" padding-top:10px">
                                                <img ID="GridView1_ctl02_Image1" Src="" 
                                                    style="border-style:None;height:98px;width:231px;border-width:0px;" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style4" colspan="2">
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp; B:-<span style="font-weight:bold;" ID="GridView1_ctl02_Label15"><input 
                                                    ID="GridView1_ctl02_RadioButton2" name="GridView1$ctl02$RadioButton2" 
                                                    onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'GridView1$ctl02$RadioButton2\',\'\')', 0)" 
                                                    type="radio" value="RadioButton2" /><label 
                                                    for="GridView1_ctl02_RadioButton2">abc</label></span>
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style9">
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp; D:-<span style="font-size:Large;font-weight:normal;"><input 
                                                    ID="GridView1_ctl02_RadioButton3" name="GridView1$ctl02$RadioButton3" 
                                                    onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'GridView1$ctl02$RadioButton3\',\'\')', 0)" 
                                                    type="radio" value="RadioButton3" /><label 
                                                    for="GridView1_ctl02_RadioButton4">abc</label></span>
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <input ID="GridView1_ctl02_Button12" name="GridView1$ctl02$Button12" 
                                                    style="color:White;background-color:#006699;border-style:None;font-size:Large;font-weight:bold;height:34px;width:230px;" 
                                                    type="submit" value="&lt;&lt;&lt;Prv" /> &nbsp;<input 
                                                    ID="GridView1_ctl02_Button2" name="GridView1$ctl02$Button2" 
                                                    style="color:White;background-color:#006699;border-style:None;font-size:Large;font-weight:bold;height:34px;width:229px;" 
                                                    type="submit" value="Mark and Next" /> 
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <input ID="GridView1_ctl02_Button1" name="GridView1$ctl02$Button1" 
                                                    style="color:White;background-color:#006699;border-style:None;font-size:Large;font-weight:bold;height:34px;width:230px;" 
                                                    type="submit" value="Save and Next" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save Answer in View-state using code
if (e.CommandName == "Save")
        {
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {

```
            if (((RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked)
            {


                Label12.Text = "A";

            }
            if (((RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton2")).Checked)
            {


                Label12.Text = "B";

            }

            if (((RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton3")).Checked)
            {


                Label12.Text = "C";




            }
            if (((RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton4")).Checked)
            {


                Label12.Text = "D";

            }
```

string m = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);

```
            ViewState[m] = Label12.Text;
```

}

Run a for Loop in Row Data Bound event of GridView1
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string id = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "id"));


        int i, j;
        for (i = 1; i <= 65; i++)
        {

            j = i + 100;
          string k = i.ToString();
            string l = j.ToString();

            if (ViewState[l] != null)
            {

                if (id == k)
                {


                    if (ViewState[l].ToString() == "A")
                    {


                        (e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton).Checked = true;
                    }
                    if (ViewState[l].ToString() == "B")
                    {


                        (e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("RadioButton2") as RadioButton).Checked = true;
                    }

                    if (ViewState[l].ToString() == "C")
                    {


                        (e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("RadioButton3") as RadioButton).Checked = true;
                    }
                    if (ViewState[l].ToString() == "D")
                    {


                        (e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("RadioButton4") as RadioButton).Checked = true;
                    }


                }

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Solve !!!!!